# Relaxed tag-wiki requirements on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, tag-wiki, privileges

I just started tooling around with the tag-wiki's on the Home Improvement stack exchange site and noticed that the requirements for creating a tag wiki seem pretty steep.  Especially the 20,000 rep requirement to edit any tag wiki.

Any chance that could be reduced for SE sites, especially while in beta?  It's nearly impossible to get 20,000 rep on most of the SE beta sites, and very difficult to get a bronze tag badge (100 upvotes) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that we have the [suggested edit feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work), *any* user can create or make modification to the tag wikis, pending approval from a moderator.

But I do agree, the privilege levels should scale with the rest of the privileges for beta sites.